# CellSignalStrengthLte shows different values in toString() than are available with getters

Tags: android, network-programming, telephony, telephonymanager, lte

The [CellSignalStrengthLte](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html) class seems to return some values with `toString()` that don't have associated getters.

Here is an example of `toString()`:

```
CellSignalStrengthLte: ss=12 rsrp=-114 rsrq=-11 rssnr=2147483647 cqi=2147483647 ta=2147483647
```

The class has 4 getters: `getAsuLevel()`, `getDbm()`, `getLevel()`, `getTimingAdvance()` here is an example of what those values return:

```
dbm: -114
asuLvl: 26
lvl: 2
timing adv: 2147483647
```

We can see that `dbm` matches up with `rsrp` from the `toString()`. And that `timingAdvance` matches up with `ta`. But none of the other values match anything that is printed with the `toString()`

My question is how do I access the other values (`ss`, `rsrq`, `rssnr` specicially) that are returned by `toString()` I could of course get the value from toString() and parse it to get the values I am interested in, but this seems backwards. Since toString() is a string that represents the object surely there must be some other way to access these values from the object.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in `CellSignalStrengthLte`, in order to get those extra fields you will have to a parse the `toString()` or use reflection to access the fields directly. Neither way is recommended for production apps.

But, you can get updates for `PhoneStateListener.onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength)` to get those values. This way, you can use public APIs to get the signal info.

- [`PhoneStateListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)
- [`CellSignalStrengthLte` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.java)